# Exception Message: Page not found. (type VssServiceResponseException) in Azure DevOps Release Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, devops, azure-deployment, azure-devops-hosted-agent

I configured the gated build, CI and CD for my current project in few weeks back, whenever I committed new changes from my development IDE like VS2017. Then I created the pull request for newly changes after few minutes the pull request and CI build succeeded. Whenever CI succeeded then the corresponding release definition triggered but not deployed it gives the error like shown in below figure.

> Exception Message: Page not found. (type VssServiceResponseException)

[image]

Few days back the same setup will work fine but suddenly the release definition will not deployed.

Comment: The error appears in which task?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk, Error doesn't appear in any task. Error occurred in the Job Phase under the release.

Comment: Also, When I browse the contents from drop in any task under release definition then it will show the error like `Page not found`.

Comment: Looks to be a temporary outage?

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsoservice/

Comment: Ok @BDarley, When it will back

Comment: @pradeep (Next Update: Before Thursday, October 25th 2018 12:55 UTC)

Comment: I am able to execute release pipelines now without the noted exceptions. This issue looks to be resolved.

Comment: Thanks @BDarley, Now I am able to execute release pipelines without any issues.